# CSS3 getting dynamic values for animations

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code that simply moves my image across the screen:

```
                /* This is the animation code. */
        @-webkit-keyframes example {
   from { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
   to   { -webkit-transform: translateX(1900px) }
}

        /* This is the element that we apply the animation to. */
        img#container {
            -webkit-animation: example 1s ease 0s 1 normal;
        }
```

The problem I can't wrap my head around is setting the translateX animation value to something calculated in javascript, such as the x position of the center of the screen. Is there any way to set the "to" attribute in javascript and then apply the id name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the **CSS3** transform values consider using **jQuery** and the [**.transit**](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) plugin. That webpage has demo's of different CSS3 animation effects explained.

**Example:**

```
$('#container').transition({ x: '1900px' });
```

Looking at their [**source code**](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.js), you will see that to do various effects in jQuery is tedious since a whole lot of relative style information is needed to created the desired output. Then to convert that jQuery into pure JavaScript equivalents is something to behold.

Test **.transit** Plugin with **translate X**: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3PrJ/)

Comment: Interesting plugin. I just need css3 animations, and this looks like it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS expression to set the JS values into your CSS class, as a example

```
height:expression(document.body.clientHeight + "px");
```

This is the way we write CSS expressions.

Comment: Can you give **translateX animation value** example?

Comment: Yes, I'm really curious what a simple example would be. Thanks

Comment: If you can set the JS value into a hidden field then you can have a try as   -webkit-transform: translateX(expression(document.getElementById('HiddenFieldId').value + "px"));. Consider the syntax, I have not tried yet.